# Playing animation with swipe controls and transform.position problem Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've set up my swipe controls to transform my player left/right/up/down and I've restricted the movement on 3 lines; -1, 0, 1. Everything works fine but the movement is not smooth at all and the player seems to be "teleporting" from one position to another. I wanted to smooth the movement by playing the animation but the result was that the animation was being played after the player has changed his position.
Is there any way to play the animation while the player is changing his position or a way to smooth the movement so it looks right ?

I've tried everything and now I'm stuck with the problem, please help

Here's my code

```cs
  public class SwipeControls : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 5.0f;
    private Vector3 startpos;  // start position
    private Vector3 endpos; //end position
    public int pozioma = 0;
    public int pionowa = 0;

    Animator anim;


    void Start() {
      GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update() {

      foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

        Vector3 newPosition;
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
          startpos = touch.position;
          endpos = touch.position;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
          endpos = touch.position;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
          newPosition = transform.position;

          if (Mathf.Abs(startpos.y - endpos.y) > Mathf.Abs(startpos.x - endpos.x)) {
            if ((startpos.y - endpos.y) > 100 && pionowa > -1) //swipe down
            {
              pionowa--;
              newPosition.y -= speed;
              transform.position = newPosition;
              anim.SetTrigger("Flydown");
            }

            if ((startpos.y - endpos.y) < -100 && pionowa < 1) //swipe up
            {
              pionowa++;
              newPosition.y += speed;
              transform.position = newPosition;
              anim.SetTrigger("Flyup");
            }
          }
          else {
            if ((startpos.x - endpos.x) > 100 && pozioma > -1)  //swipe left
            {
              pozioma--;
              newPosition.z -= speed;
              transform.position = newPosition;
              anim.SetTrigger("Flyleft");
            }
          }

          if ((startpos.x - endpos.x) < -100 && pozioma < 1) //swipe right
          {
            pozioma++;
            newPosition.z += speed;
            transform.position = newPosition;
            anim.SetTrigger("Flyright");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code instead of using just

```
transform.position = newPosition;
```

in all position use

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
```

where smooth is float variable assign it required value may be 0.5f or whatever you want

Note : What it actually does is that it makes game object to move little based on smooth value, every frame

Comment: The issue with that usage of `Lerp` is it never reaches an exact position! Instead it gets very close and very slow. This is ideal when stabilizing e.g. a cursor but not an optional solution in this case where the OP might to move to an exact position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything, it's still the same. Any other idea ?

Comment: Try @derHugo answer by using coroutines by the way when you used above code is it just teleported to that new place or doesn't moved at all?

Comment: It's basically the same as it was without Lerp

Answer (score 0):

Note that we do not know your animator setup. If in those animation clips there is anywhere a keyframe for the position then the animator will always overrule anything done by scripts!

---

Instead of setting the new position immediately you could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) with [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) like (also fixing some coding styles)

```
public class SwipeControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Flag for ignoring input until current animation finished
    private bool routineRunning;

    // Configure in the Inspector distance to swipe
    // in unity units
    [SerializeField] private float swipeDistance = 5;

    // configure this in the Inspector
    // How long should the swiping take in seconds
    [SerializeField] private float swipeDuration = 1;

    private Vector3 _startpos;  // start position
    private Vector3 _endpos; //end position

    public int pozioma = 0;
    public int pionowa = 0;

    private Animator _anim;


    private void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Ignore any Input while a routine is running
        if (routineRunning) return;

        foreach (var touch in Input.touches)
        {
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    _startpos = touch.position;
                    _endpos = touch.position;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    _endpos = touch.position;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    if (Mathf.Abs(_startpos.y - _endpos.y) > Mathf.Abs(_startpos.x - _endpos.x))
                    {
                        if (_startpos.y - _endpos.y > 100 && pionowa > -1) //swipe down
                        {
                            pionowa--;
                            StartCoroutine(MoveSmooth(Vector3.up * -1, swipeDuration));
                            _anim.SetTrigger("Flydown");
                        }
                        else if (_startpos.y - _endpos.y < -100 && pionowa < 1) //swipe up
                        {
                            pionowa++;
                            StartCoroutine(MoveSmooth(Vector3.up, swipeDuration));
                            _anim.SetTrigger("Flyup");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_startpos.x - _endpos.x > 100 && pozioma > -1) //swipe left
                        {
                            pozioma--;
                            StartCoroutine(MoveSmooth(Vector3.forward * -1, swipeDuration));
                            _anim.SetTrigger("Flyleft");
                        }
                        else if (_startpos.x - _endpos.x < -100 && pozioma < 1) //swipe right
                        {
                            pozioma++;
                            StartCoroutine(MoveSmooth(Vector3.forward, swipeDuration));
                            _anim.SetTrigger("Flyright");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveSmooth(Vector3 direction, float duration)
    {
        routineRunning = true;

        var currentPosition = transform.localPosition;
        var targetPosition = currentPosition + direction * swipeDistance;

        var timePassed = 0f;
        do
        {
            // Additionally add some ease in and out to the movement to get 
            // even smoother movement
            var lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, timePassed / duration);

            // Interpolate the position between currentPosition and targetPosition
            // using the factor between 0 and 1
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, targetPosition, lerpFactor);

            // increase by time since last frame
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            // let this frame render and go on from
            // here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        } while (timePassed <= duration);

        // To avoid over or undershooting in the end set a fixed value
        transform.localPosition = targetPosition;

        routineRunning = false;
    }
}
```

---

I don't know why you are using `y+=` and `z+=` .. it seems to me that it meeans the Camera is facing left in your scene e.g. with `rotation = 0, -90, 0` and e.g. `position = 10, 0, 0` than this should be the result (**Note** I copied the same code into `if(GetMouseButtonDown(0))` etc in order to simulate the touch on the PC.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So right now it is much more smooth movement but it's responding only for the right swipe and instead of going right it's going backwards plus without any restrictions. I can't solve the issue

Comment: The reason why I'm using y and z axis is because I've imported my character model from blender and my left and right swipes are controlled on the z axis

Comment: I don't know if it matters (because it doesn't affect player's swipe movement) but the character is a child to an empty game objet which contains the waypoint path so the player is moving forward on a path

Comment: In this case you might want to replace `Vector3.up` and `Vector3.forward` (which are Unity global vectors) rather with `transform.up` and `transform.forward` or maybe even `transform.right` (which are the objects local direction vectors) and play with the directions (`* -1`)

Comment: I've created a new scene with player, no path and changed Vector3 to transform and it's working but when the player is on a path it's just moving without any restriction backwards no matter in which direction I swipe

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without a coroutine ?

Comment: a lot ^^ But first you should try to everywhere instead use `localPosition` instead (but than again with `Vector3.up` etc). This should do the trick as long as your child object is not somehow rotated as well while following the track (if the parent is it shouldn't matter)?

Comment: So it's working, THANK YOU! But I have another question(lol) to this. Right now if my player is going straight I can swipe left/right but when the player is rotating by 90* (because it's a child of the camera) the left/right controls are turning into forward/backwards. How can I "lock" my swipes to stay exactly the same no matter how I'll rotate my player ?